# Patrón de diseño Unit of Work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

El patrón de diseño Unit of Work, sirve para abstraer el context y para coordinar las operaciones.
¿Es recomendable su implementación? estoy usando Entity Framework code first, yo lo utilizaría al momento de guardar una cabecera/detalle.

Comment: El patrón Unit of Work tiene más sentido cuando realizas transacciones con múltiples operaciones y afectas a más de una tabla. Si no tienes operaciones de ese tipo en tu aplicación, no tiene mucho sentido su uso.

Comment: Luiggi, gracias por responder, en tonces lo puedo tener implementado y usarlo cuando lo necesite.

Comment: En teoría, así es.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay que diferenciar lo que es puramente el Patrón Unit of Work y su implementación en Entity Framework y su uso con Entity Framework

## Patrón Unit Of Work

El patrón Unit Of Work es descrito por [Matin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) como

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of concurrency problems.

Traducción mía

> Mantiene una lista de objetos afectados por una transacción de negocio y coordina la escritura de los cambios y la resolución de problemas de concurrencia.

Lo que quiere decir esto es que se trata de un patrón en el cual internamente el objeto `Unit of Work` mantiene una lista de cambios a las entidades o demás operaciones a realizar, y cuando se desean escribir en la base de datos, se ejecuta como una única operación (transacciòn).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso de cabecera de detalle efectivamente es una situación donde en un único `Unit of Work` se mentienen los cambios tanto a la cabecera como a las filas relacionadas y con un solo método del Unit of Work se persiste todo en una única transacción.

## Implementación en Entity Framework

Si estás usando directamente Entity Framework, sin ninguna abstracción por encima la clase `DbContext`(o anteriormente `ObjectContext`) ya implementa este patrón.

Es decir cuando modificas objetos obtenidos del `DbContext` (a través de uno de sus `DbSet<T>`, los añades o eliminas, estás manteniendo esta lista de cambios en memoria.

Estos cambios serán aplicados cuando ejecutes el método [`.SaveChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx) o [`.SaveChangesAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync(v=vs.113).aspx)

Como verás ya no es necesario volver a implementar por encima esta abstracción, ya que al ejecutar `.SaveChanges()` Entity Framework generará el SQL correspondiente a todos los cambios y los ejecutará dentro de una transacción.

Comment: Carlos, entonces el patrón de diseño Unit of Work se implementa en aplicaciones que no trabajen con Entity Framewor?, ¿con que proposito esta creado si EF ya trae uno? me imagino que EF tambien se puede usar comit

Comment: El método commit descrito por Fowler corresponde al método `.SaveChanges()` de EntityFramework. Además el patrón unit of work generalmente se implementa en ORMs de modo la complejidad de mantener la lista de cambios, y posteriormente generar los comandos correctos a la base de datos está abstraido y el programador no se tenga que preocupar de esto. Si no tienes alguna necesidad adicional realmente no tiene sentido implementar por encima alguna otra abstracción.

Comment: Si por el contrario sí tienes alguna necesidad adicional en el proyecto por ejemplo: Que el modelo no dependa de la tecnología específica, de modo que no te amarres a EF. O que por ejemplo la aplicación pueda ser instalada con dos repositorios de datos a elección del usuario, una sea una base de datos y otra almacenar la información en archivos XML, ahí si convendría realizar una capa de mas alto nivel en la cual la implementación que va a trabajar contra la base de datos simplemente delegue las llamadas a EntityFramework, siendo la otra libre de hacerlo de otra forma

Comment: En verdad si lo tengo implementado pero no lo estoy usando, voy a usarlo cuando haga multiples transaciones como cabecera detalle y restar estock

Comment: Tengo entendido que es necesario para el caso de que dos DbSet<> de entidades diferentes hagan operaciones relacionadas (la típica operación de guardar cabecera y detalle de factura como mencionaste). Si esto no se ejecuta como una única transacción se corre el riesgo de que los datos queden inconsistentes en caso de el fallo de alguna, aunque estoy investigando igual que vos, así que puedo estar equivocado. Si ese es el caso espero a que alguien me corrija... Saludos!!

Comment: @SaidJacobo no entiendo a que te refieres. Como ya mencioné antes el `DbContext` el cual puede contener múltiples `DbSet` implementa el patrón UoW

Comment: No sé soluciona este tema con transacciones en ef?